# Stopping LINQ from querying entity sets (and grouping)

Tags: linq-to-sql

This is a brief description of my db. You have **issues** which have **categories**. I have various queries that get issues based on all sorts of criteria, but that's not important to the question.

I want to be able to take a list of issues I have queried, lets say for example, that occured yesterday and group them by category.

I have a method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Category> GroupIssuesByCategory(IEnumerable<Issue> issues)
{
    return from i in issues
        group i by i.Category into c
        select c.key
}
```

Category has a nice mapping which allows it to list Issues within it. That's great for what I want, but in this scenario, it will pull back **all** the issues in that category, rather than the ones from the set I provided. How do I get around this?

Can I get around this?

---

I worked out why my original code wasn't compiling and updated the question.

Alas, I still have my main problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the second part of the question, but your compilation problem is that the return type of a grouping is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Category, Issue>>`, which I think is what you are looking to return from your method. Also, you don't really need the `into c select c` bit - that's only useful if you want to do some processing on the result of the grouping to get a different list.

`IGrouping<S,T>` has a key property which is the `Category` value, and is `IEnumerable<T>` to give you the list of `Issues` in that `Category`.

Try this as your method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<Category, Issue>> GroupIssuesByCategory(IEnumerable<Issue> issues)
{
    return from i in issues
        group i by i.Category;
}
```